# Multiplication by $p$ after faithfully flat base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

I was trying to understand the fppf topology for schemes and I found this question.

Consider any base scheme $S$ and let $G$ be a commutative $S$-group scheme locally (for the étale topology on $S$) free and finite. Consider the multiplication by $p$. Is it true that there exists a faithfully flat base change $S^{\prime}\rightarrow S$ such that the base change of the multiplication by $p$ is an epimorphism for the fppf topology, i.e. a faithfully flat morphism? Is it important to consider multiplication by $p$ or can we argue the same for some particular classes of maps?

I don't have any idea of how to discuss such kind of problems!

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What does 'locally free and finite' mean? Do you mean that $G/S$ is a finite etale group scheme?

Comment: No, I mean that for each point of the base $S$ there is an étale neighborhood $U$, say affine, such that the base change $G\times_{S}U$ is affine and represented by a finite free algebra over the algebra representing $U$.

Comment: So, in particular, you're assuming that $G$ is quasi-coherent?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming quasi-coherency!